# Composer package with dependencies giving me error

Tags: composer-php

I don't understand why this error is occurring as each project is published on packagist using only master:

**composer.json** of second project

```
{
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "vendor/project1": "dev-master"
    }   
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for VENDOR/PROJECT2 dev-master -> satisfiable by VENDOR/PROJECT2[dev-master].
    - VENDOR/PROJECT2 dev-master requires VENDOR/PROJECT1 dev-master -> satisfiable by VENDOR/PROJECT1[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` help?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) settings. By default this is set to `stable`, which will not allow installing unstable package unless you explicitly declare that you want it. You may fix this in 2 ways:

1. Allow to install unstable dependencies. Add this to your `composer.json`:

   ```
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true,
   ```

   [`prefer-stable`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable) ensures that you will get stable package if it exist - without this setting Composer will install everything from dev branches, and you probably don't want this.
2. Explicitly require package in unstable version:

   ```
   "require": {
       ...
       "VENDOR/PROJECT1": "dev-master"
   },
   ```

Both solutions works only if you do this in `composer.json` of your main app.